Google Vertex AI Have to increase quota, even though usage is low
I'm trying to build an app that will enable AI to generate information, about how much water each plant needs. WHen I do it on their website, it works, however, on my computer, I get these errors:
/home/antoni/Desktop/New folder 21_14/plants/node_modules/@google-cloud/vertexai/build/src/models/chat_session.js:127
            throw new errors_1.GoogleGenerativeAIError('exception appending chat history', e);
                  ^

GoogleGenerativeAIError: [VertexAI.GoogleGenerativeAIError]: exception appending chat history
    at /home/antoni/Desktop/New folder 21_14/plants/node_modules/@google-cloud/vertexai/build/src/models/chat_session.js:127:19
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  stack_trace: ClientError: [VertexAI.ClientError]: got status: 429 Too Many Requests. {"error":{"code":429,"message":"Quota exceeded for aiplatform.googleapis.com/generate_content_requests_per_minute_per_project_per_base_model with base model: chat-bison-32k. Please submit a quota increase request. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/quotas-genai.","status":"RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"}}
      at throwErrorIfNotOK (/home/antoni/Desktop/New folder 21_14/plants/node_modules/@google-cloud/vertexai/build/src/functions/post_fetch_processing.js:31:19)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async generateContentStream (/home/antoni/Desktop/New folder 21_14/plants/node_modules/@google-cloud/vertexai/build/src/functions/generate_content.js:92:5) {
    stack_trace: undefined
  }
}

Node.js v18.19.0

I also use ADC authentication.
const {VertexAI} = require('@google-cloud/vertexai');
var project = "generator-406917";
var location = 'us-central1';
var model = 'chat-bison-32k';

const vertex_ai = new VertexAI({project: project, location: location});

const generativeModel = vertex_ai.getGenerativeModel({
    model: model
});

async function generatePlantDataForAWeek(plantName) {
  var userData = `I'm creating a machine which will automatically water plants that are in closed containers, the time of the year is spring, based on this, return me the 
  Optimal water amount for one week, how much per day, whether every day or only on some days,
    for an apple tree planted at home, in an container, which is going to be only waterred automatically by the answers you give.
  You have to give back an array that has seven items, like this:
  plantWaterData = {
  
   plantWater: [110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110],
  },
    The numbers in plantWater are just an example, but they are in ml,
  You can change the numbers, so that they are correct, and show the amount of water an apple tree needs in the first stage of growth,
  only return the array`;
  const chat = generativeModel.startChat();
  const chatInput1 = "How can I learn more about Node.js?";
  const result1 = await chat.sendMessageStream(userData);
  for await (const item of result1.stream) {
      console.log(item.candidates[0].content.parts[0].text);
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(await result1.response));
  console.log(result1);
  };

generatePlantDataForAWeek("");
```[AI usage](https://i.sstatic.net/HaPWw.jpg)
[AI usage](https://i.sstatic.net/0ODYc.jpg)



I tried diffrent articles, but nothing worked.


You are exceeding the requests per minute. Are you using the free API? The free API only allows 2 requests per minute. The Pay as you go pricing model will be available in May 2024 which increases the limits. Solution: slow down the request rate. Implement Exponential Backoff and Retry in your application.

I get this error after changing to gemini: node getPlantData2.cjs {"candidates":[{"content":{"role":"model","parts":[{"text":"plantWaterData ="}]}}]} {"candidates":[{"finishReason":"OTHER"}],"usageMetadata":{"promptTokenCount":209,"candidatesTokenCount":4,"totalTokenCount":213}} /home/antoni/Desktop/New folder 21_14/plants/node_modules/@google-cloud/vertexai/build/src/functions/post_fetch_processing.js:175

I do not understand your comment. Also, do not use comments to add information. Edit your question instead.

check quota info here https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/quotas
